# Configure Zeitgeist to show frequently accessed files in Dash

Tags: files, unity-dash, zeitgeist

Four years later, Dash still [shows irrelevant results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202828/dash-is-slow-and-shows-irrelevant-results) when I search for files.

I have a file "Expenses.xlsx" that I open and save every day. However, when I search for "exp", even "Expenses", I get first almost completely irrelevant results:

[image]

One of those "expenses" folder (which? the UI is useless here) does have the .xlsx, but `Yoga @ Cindy's.png` is a file I haven't opened since 2+ months ago, and I have no idea what "Internet Explorer IE.txt" is (I could check, but the point is that I don't open the file often enough to know).

The sorting algorithm is just wrong. `Yoga @ Cindy` doesn't even contain "exp", it only is located in the "expenses" directory, but "Expenses.xlsx" is in that same directory, *plus* contains the search query in its name.

So is there a way to bias/tune Zeitgeist to show firt recently modified files that match, or in general, files whose name does match the search query?

If not, where do I file a bug for this? Launchpad [points](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zeitgeist) to FreeDesktop, but I [couldn't find anything there](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=recent&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&product=Zeitgeist&query_format=specific).

The only workaround I found is to press Super+F and type "exp", which limits the scope to Files. Still, `Yoga @ Cindy's` shows up before `Expenses.xlsx`.

Comment: While not specifically a dash solution, look at couple answers posted here: http://askubuntu.com/q/803869/295286  There's two indicators for recently used files. Might be a worthy alternative

Comment: Why not just make a keyboard shortcut to open your file directly since you need to access it frequently? Point your keyboard shortcut to `libreoffice --calc /path/to/Expenses/Expenses.xlsx`. BTW, people recommend that you work with and save files in the program's native format (`.ods`) and save as `.xlsx` only when you want to share the file with a Windows user.

Comment: @DKBose, good idea to make a shortcut. I use Excel with WINE due to [serious problems I've encountered with LibreCalc](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?email1=dascalescu&emailreporter1=1&emailtype1=substring&list_id=620680&order=changeddate%20DESC%2C), including file corruption.